# Add Items to Custom Class List

Tags: c#

I was wondering if someone could help me.  I have 2 classes:

```
`public class EventPutDto
{
    //public string id { get; set; }
    public string eventGbsCode { get; set; }
    //public string portfolioId { get; set; }
    public string businessUnitId { get; set; }
    public List<Multilingual> multilingual { get; set; }
    public bool supportedInPlatform { get; set; }
    public bool gbsEnabled { get; set; }
    public bool isParticipationEvent { get; set; }
}`

public class Multilingual
{
    public string locale { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
}
```

I want to add a name and locale to the list property in the eventPutDto class.  How do I do it? For example I want to add 3 locales so it should be something like

```
"en-gb" - "english name",
"it-it" - "italian name",
"es-es" - "spanish name"
```

I need to know this as I'm trying to post some Json to an endpoint.

Comment: Have you tried anything?  What didn't work?  When you did a Google search for something like "add item to list in C#" what did you find and where did you get stuck?

Comment: You need to instantiate that multilingual list with "new", then add your items.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like what you want is a dictionary.

So, `locale` should not be of type `string`, but a `Dictionary<string, string>`

Read up on them, they are a collection of keys and values.